# Rails-UJS response rendering raw html instead of interpreted haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, rails-ujs

- Rails 6.0.1.2 using Webpacker
- Kaminari gem
- haml
- Rails-ujs

I am implementing an infinite-scroll feature using the kaminari gem for pagination and rails-ujs.

The partial loads fine on the initial page view. It displays the results (each result is a card rendered from a partial called ‘rooms_card.html.haml’

Rendering the rooms_card partial on the index.html.haml page as a collection.

```
= render partial: "rooms_card", collection: @rooms, as: :room, cached: true
```

[image: initial page render]

However, when I click on the ‘View More’ link, the request is made and the result is appended, but it is raw html displayed instead of interpreted.

[image: raw html appended instead of rendered]

Here is the code for the link.

```
= link_to_next_page @rooms, "View More", class: "view-more-link", remote: true}
```

From my index.js.haml file

```
document.getElementById("rooms-cards").append("#{j render(partial: "rooms/rooms_card", collection: @rooms, as: :room) }")
```

My respond to block. 
rooms_controller.rb

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @results, each_serializer: RoomSerializer }
    end
```

How can I get response to render in the browser instead of displaying the raw html?

I have squinted at this everyway I know how. Any ideas on what I am missing?

Thank you!

Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass a `String` (`DOMString` to be precise) object to the [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) method, it will be inserted as a [`Text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) node. Pass a [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) object instead.

```
const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = "#{j render(partial: 'rooms/rooms_card', collection: @rooms, as: :room)}"
document.getElementById("rooms-cards").append(wrapper);
```

If you don't want to create an additional `div`, you can use [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment).

```
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragment.innerHTML = "#{j render(partial: 'rooms/rooms_card', collection: @rooms, as: :room)}"
document.getElementById("rooms-cards").append(fragment);
```

Hope this helps.